# Question regarding the total cost of a tree for a code proof

Tags: algorithms, huffman-coding

The question is: "Prove that we can also express the total cost of a tree for a code as the sum, over all internal nodes, of the combined frequencies of the two children of the node."

I found an answer here (16.3-4): https://walkccc.me/CLRS/Chap16/16.3/, but I'm confused about one part of it.

Specifically I'm confused about this part of the proof:

$$ \begin{aligned} B(T) & = \sum_{\text{leaves }l \in T} f(l)d_T(l) \\ & = \sum_{l \ne c_1, c_2} f(l)d_T(l) + f(c_1)(d_T(c_1) - 1) + f(c_2)(d_T(c_2) - 1) + f(c_1) + f(c_2) \\ & = \sum_{\text{internal nodes }i'\in T'} f(\text{child}_1\text{ of }i') + f(\text{child}_2\text{ of }i') + f(c_1) + f(c_2) \\ & = \sum_{\text{internal nodes }i\in T} f(\text{child}_1\text{ of }i) + f(\text{child}_1\text{ of }i). \end{aligned} $$

How do we get from here:

$$\sum_{l \ne c_1, c_2} f(l)d_T(l) + f(c_1)(d_T(c_1) - 1) + f(c_2)(d_T(c_2) - 1) + f(c_1) + f(c_2)$$

to here:

$$\sum_{\text{internal nodes }i'\in T'} f(\text{child}_1\text{ of }i') + f(\text{child}_2\text{ of }i') + f(c_1) + f(c_2)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different proof. Denote the frequency of a node $x$ by $w(x)$ and its cost by $c(x)$, and let $x \prec y$ denote that $x$ is a leaf which is a descendant of the internal node $y$. Thus $$ w(y) = \sum_{x \preceq y} w(x). $$
The sum of all frequencies is
$$
 \sum_{\text{internal }y} w(y) = \sum_{\text{internal }y} \sum_{\substack{\text{leaf }x\text{ s.t.}\\ x \prec y}} w(x) = \sum_{\text{leaf }x} \sum_{\substack{\text{internal }y\text{ s.t.}\\x \prec y}} w(x) = \sum_{\text{leaf }x} c(x) w(x),
$$
since $x$ has exactly $c(x)$ internal nodes $y$ of which it is a descendant.